# Unexpected behaviour of generator nested in a comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, generator, dictionary-comprehension

I get an unexpected behaviour in Python when using a generator nested inside a comprehension, a dictionary comprehension in this specific case below. More specifically, consider the following simple comprehension:

```py
D = {x : (y for y in range(5) if y==x) for x in range(5)}
```

I would have expected to obtain a dictionary `D` such that `list(D[x]) == [x]` for every integer i from 0 to 4. Instead, the result is

```py
>>> list(D[0])
[4]
>>> list(D[1])
[4]
>>> list(D[2])
[4]
>>> list(D[3])
[4]
>>> list(D[4])
[4]
```

I think that this is happening because the value of the variable `x` used to define the generator is changing until is fixed to 4. However, I thought that each generator should get defined with the exact value of the variable at the time of the definition. Is there an alternative way to this simple nested structure in a corrected way and with expected results?

Note that the realising the generator into a list would fix the behaviour:

```py
D = {x : list((y for y in range(5) if y==x)) for x in range(5)}
```

but I am interested in solutions that preserve the use of generators.

Comment: Each generator is only going to yield one element; why bother? Or do you think that one generator will be shared by all 5 keys? That's not how a `dict` works.

Comment: `x` is just a free variable inside the generator; its value won't be looked up until yo actually *iterate* over the generator.

Comment: It is not clear why you need the inner comprehension? Use a `lambda` instead!

Comment: The example is just a toy example to easily investigate this unexpected behaviour, inspired by a more meaningful case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is a free variable, so its value won't be considered until you actually iterate over the generator. This, as you've noticed, means that the value of `x` can change between when the generator is defined and when you actually use it.

There's no way to pass a value into a generator expression; you'll have to use a generator function:

```
def make_generator(x):
    for y in range(5):
        if y == x:
            yield y

D = {x: make_generator(x) for x in range(5)}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the scenario you have described (*I do not understand why you need the inner comprehension*), you may simply use the following:

```py
d = {x:lambda x: [x] for x in range(5)}
print(d[3](3))
```

which will give:

```bash
[3]
```